# find the maximum value of $\left(\int_{0}^1\sqrt[3]{f(x)}dx\right)\left(\int_{0}^1\sqrt[5]{f(x)}dx\right)\left(\int_{0}^1\sqrt[7]{f(x)}dx\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

If $f:[0,1]\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ is a continuous function such that $\int_{0}^1f(x)dx=1$ then find the maximum possible value of $$\left(\int_{0}^1\sqrt[3]{f(x)}dx\right)\left(\int_{0}^1\sqrt[5]{f(x)}dx\right)\left(\int_{0}^1\sqrt[7]{f(x)}dx\right)$$

How should one choose $f(x)$. Or is there a general version of Cauchy Schwarz Bunyavosky's inequality

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, Hölders inequality (or the fact that $t \mapsto t^{1/p}$ is concave) immediately shows that each factor is $\le 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By H"older's inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality
(with $p=3,5,7$ respectively), each of the integrals in the product is at most 1. So $f=1$ is the maximizer.